# Define CONSTANT not working, why?

Tags: php, constants, require-once

I've defined on config.php:

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
```

and on index.php:

```
require_once (ROOT.'/header.php');
```

result:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT'

Why ROOT constant isn't working? I'm learning, someone could explain me?

**EDIT**

If I put:

```
require_once (__DIR__.'/header.php');
```

It works. Someone could explain me why?

Comment: Are you ever including your config.php in index.php? If not, then ROOT won't be defined in index.php

Comment: Did you `require_once "config.php"` ?

Comment: My header.php includes functions.php / config.php is included inside functions.php. / Index.php includes header.php. Maybe is the order? Should I put it in another place?

Comment: You'd be better defining ROOT at the top of  your index.php; because it's index.php that's called first, and the CONSTANT will only be available after it's defined, but then available throughout all the files that you subsequently include

Comment: You're trying to use the constant before it's defined. You're including `header.php` using the constant, but the constant is defined only after header.php > functions.php > config.php is included...

Comment: So what's the best approach to define directories? Shouldn't I put them on functions.php? I don't want to change DIR PATH in all pages if I change my server.

Comment: The constant will not be loaded until AFTER the file that defines has been included/required, so you're trying to eat your cake before it's even been baked.

Comment: I removed RESOLVED from the title. Either post your own answer, ask for someone to post an answer with detailed information, or delete the question, *you have choices*. If you're to post your own answer, please be specific. Remember, others stand at visiting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working cause ROOT was defined inside 'header.php'.

It needs to be defined before call header.php.

Thanks for any help.